# Disable auto-linking phone on specific div ios

Tags: ios, hyperlink, tel

I have a phonegap app which displays some information (uses AngularJs and JQM, don't think it's relevant).

I have a div that contains a certain number:

```
<div class="class ng-bindig">1234567</div>
```

ios automatically detects it as a valid phone number and inserts a link to dail, even though it's not an actual phone number.

I've found the following solution:
http://www.darowski.com/tracesofinspiration/2009/03/31/stop-iphone-from-incorrectly-auto-linking-phone-numbers/

However, this disables ALL phone links, even ones that I created on purpose with:

```
<a href="tel:...">Call me</a>
```

Any ideas how I can disable the auto linking for that certain part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
<a href="tel:..." onclick='return true'>Call me</a>
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Tested example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="return true;">Yahoo (Working)</a>
        <br />
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="return false;">Yahoo (Not Working)</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

## [Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2ta2/)

Comment: Works great! You still have to manually remove the link styling though. Thank you :)

Comment: in css we will disable linking... but for tel: we will sat return true